# views.log_in didn't return an HttpResponse object

Tags: django, python-3.x

Whenever a user enters a blank password (or username) and login, it shows this error:

```
ValueError at /
The view views.log_in didn't return an HttpResponse object.
```

code:

```
def log_in(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.cleaned_data['username']
            pword = form.cleaned_data['password']
            user = authenticate(username=user, password=pword)
            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                if request.GET.get('next') is not None:
                    return HttpResponseRedirect(request.GET.get('next'))
                else:
                    return HttpResponseRedirect('/home/')
            else:
                return render(request, 'login.html', { 'logform': form, 'error': True})
    else:
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/home/')
        else:
            form = LoginForm()
            return render(request, 'login.html', { 'logform': form, })
```

How would I fix this error? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have no return value when the form is invalid. The usual choice is to de-indent the `return render(...` line so that executes any time none of your redirects are triggered, rendering the invalid form with its errors:

```
def log_in(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # as above
    else:
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/home/')
        else:
            form = LoginForm()
    return render(request, 'login.html', { 'logform': form, })
```

Comment: I did that way, it does not show an error if there is no input in password or username. However, if I enter wrong username and password, it shows an error.

Comment: Are you checking the form's errors, or are you looking for the `'error'=True` value you put in the context when your username/password doesn't authenticate? You could also set that value when the form is invalid if you're looking at that variable to show an error, or you could have your template check `form.is_bound and not form.is_valid`.

Comment: I cannot find the example of a template check form.is_bound and not form.is_valid. Guide me, please?

Comment: Presumably you have something like `{% if error %}` in your template. You could change that to `{% if error or logform.is_bound and not logform.is_valid %}`, at least if you're on a vaguely recent version of Django.